# javascript match only some steps of regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to check if string matches part of regex state:
lets say I have `/^12345$/`. I wan't to achieve something like that `"123".match(/^12345$/, match_3_steps_only) = true`. It is easy when regex is simply a string, but is it built in or I have to write my own parser for this?

Comment: [This sounds like an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you **actually** trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes and no, but it depends on the problem, can you explain the issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: @atmd I want to allow people to enter only strings matching specified regex.

Comment: @zzzzBov I want to allow people to enter only strings matching specified regex.

Comment: @user2349668, `"123"` **does not match** the specified regex. Your comment directly conflicts with the question you've asked. Please add some *real* examples of *real* input that you expect to match, and *real* input that you expect to not match.

Answer (score 0):

As in http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp the syntax of `match` is

```
string.match(regexp)
```

So there is no other built in parameters as in your example.

But you could modify your regex like so `/^1(2(3(45?)?)?)?$/`. That will match `1`, `12`, `123`, `1234` and `12345`.

http://regexr.com/3arbc

Comment: Yes, but constructing regexes like this one for more complicated inputs is daunting task and there should be possibility to specify how many steps(states) of regex you want to have satisfied.